# How to pull a word out of a list then shuffle the word?

Tags: python, shuffle

So I want to pull a word out of a list, then I want to jumble the word so I will have to guess what the mixed up word is. Once guessed correctly, will move onto the next word.

My code so far:

```
import random

words = ['Jumble', 'Star', 'Candy', 'Wings', 'Power', 'String', 'Shopping', 'Blonde', 'Steak', 'Speakers', 'Case', 'Stubborn', 'Cat', 'Marker', 'Elevator', 'Taxi', 'Eight', 'Tomato', 'Penguin', 'Custard']

from random import shuffle
shuffle(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to import shuffle it is already imported with random

Comment: Ah well, it is completely normal then it's kinda different at the begining but is a good choice if you ask me :) have fun

Answer (score 0):

Pls kindly noted that `shuffle()` changes the input parameter *in-place* which it will always return a `None` .

As Kevin suggested, you can pick a random word by `random.choice()` and feed word as below showing:

I thinking you are trying to do like

```
sorted(words[2], key=lambda k: random.random())
# ['y', 'd', 'a', 'C', 'n']
```

you can join it by :

```
''.join(sorted(words[2], key=lambda k: random.random()))
# 'andCy'
```

Comment: How do i print this out? print ___?

Comment: you can use lots of ways , you can print out by `print` also save it into a string ,then dump to a text file ..

Answer (score 0):

Start with your code:

```
import random

words = ['Jumble', 'Star', 'Candy', 'Wings', 'Power', 'String', 'Shopping', 'Blonde', 'Steak', 'Speakers', 'Case', 'Stubborn', 'Cat', 'Marker', 'Elevator', 'Taxi', 'Eight', 'Tomato', 'Penguin', 'Custard']
```

Use `random.choice()` to grab a single word:

```
chosen = random.choice(words)
```

If you want to grab multiple words and deal with them one at a time, you can use `random.sample()` instead.  If you want to deal with every single word, you can use `random.shuffle()` as you've already done and then iterate over `words` (with `for word in words: ...`).

Finally, shuffle the word:

```
letters = list(chosen)  # list of all the letters in chosen, in order
random.shuffle(letters)
scrambled = ''.join(letters)
```

Comment: This looks like it will work, thanks! How do I print them out?

Comment: Use `print(scrambled)`.  In Python 3 the parenthesis are mandatory, while they are optional in Python 2 (i.e. you can write `print scrambled` in Python 2).

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
for w in words:
    s = list(w)
    shuffle(s)
    print ''.join(s)
```

Convert each word into list first before you apply shuffle to each word. Then join them together